# Javascript file with .css extension

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have a JavaScript file with .css extension instead and still work inside the `<script src="myJs.js"></script>`?

Reason? webs.com won't accept .js files unless you're a Pro user. I've tried using Dropbox as host, but it becomes too slow.

Comment: Just add your JS inline until you can upgrade?

Comment: An interesting question -- why not go ahead and try it. (My bet is it's browser-dependent. Is it possible to give an executable (.exe) the extension ".js" and so force a browser to run it? Or will it attempt to 'parse' that file anyway as Javascript?)

Comment: I did try. And it seemed to work on Chrome despite it having a .css extension. It ran just fine.

Comment: FYI, I'd be wary about trying to game the company like this. They could remove your account if it violates any of their guidelines.

Comment: Refering to the question above. I would put it inline, but my idea is that I'm making someone a webpage to put his info in. So I'm giving them just the base neccessary, while the needed rest is written by JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to force content type in the script tag ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJs.css"></script>
```